# EditText background color works incorrectly after app goes to background

Tags: android, android-layout

I change the background colour of my EditText from blue to red. When I put my app in the background (press menu button) and reopen it from opened apps menu the colour changes to the default colour.

I tried to force-change it to red in onResume() but it doesn't work.

My EditText is inside the TextInputLayout

Any clues, community? Thanks in advance!

**This is how it looks in normal way after I init error on EditText**
[image]

**After that I hide the app and reopen it from the launched apps**
[image]

**And it becomes like that**
[image]

**Error init code**

```
 private void initPasswordError() {
inputPassword.getBackground()
    .setColorFilter(ContextCompat
            .getColor(getApplicationContext(), com.example.easyplanet.R.color.watermelon),
        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
clearPasswordField.setImageResource(com.example.easyplanet.R.drawable.ic_clear_red);
setInputTextLayoutColor(passwordTextInputLayout, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.watermelon));
```

}

**I need the EditText background remain red after reopening app from background**

Comment: please post the screenshots and your code with desired output

Comment: @AshishRanjan, I've added screenshots and code snippet. Please, take a look. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's about the focus. You can request focus on your editText in onResume.